# How to get equidistant points from a linestring (geographical coordinates)

Tags: bash, awk, gdal

I want to resample geographical coordinates based on a specific number of values, let's say, 1663 for the following case:

```
-78.0599088 -11.89402416
-78.04317744 -11.88622134
-78.0267798 -11.87700462
-78.010353 -11.8692050399999
-77.9953194 -11.86129017
-77.96128788 -11.8449840599999
-77.92870572 -11.82838707
-77.89554864 -11.8117820699999
-77.86357524 -11.79488952
-77.83013412 -11.77942518
-77.7978615599999 -11.76223743
-77.765589 -11.7456140699999
-77.73216732 -11.72927727
-77.6996085599999 -11.7117892799999
-77.6673594 -11.6965884599999
-77.63510052 -11.6819618399999
-77.6045808 -11.6618759099999
-77.57262108 -11.6432262
-77.5406624399999 -11.62628883
-77.5072638 -11.6099197199999
-77.4753066 -11.5923951899999
-77.4427813199999 -11.57658786
-77.4093902399999 -11.5599159
-77.38064244 -11.5446833099999
```

However, the tricky part here is to keep the first and last positions and to use open-source software tools (such as GDAL, AWK, GMT or other bash shell command line tools, that would be great).

As example I am looking for something similar to the "Equidistant points (fixed number)" option of XTools Pro: https://help.xtools.pro/pro/12.2/en/XTools_Pro_Components/Feature_conversions/Convert_Features_to_Points.htm

Here an expected output, a line of distance X from which 7 points (node or vertex) were created considering the first and last positions:

[image]

Any support is appreciated.

Comment: Not clear, could you please show us expected output too?

Comment: I added the expected output, please find also a link with a commercial tool that does what I ask here.

Comment: It was redundant, I removed that part.

Comment: what are the expected output values, you posted a graph which is not very useful for comparison purposes.  What if your data points are not aligned?  Do you sample on the generated non-linear path?

Comment: good point, I expect values aligned as in the figure, it is like creating nodes along the line.

Comment: I believe what you are searching for is : http://edwilliams.org/avform.htm especially the section on intermediate points (http://edwilliams.org/avform.htm#Intermediate)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python did the trick:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import csv

with open('input_xy.txt') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    xy_floats = map(lambda x: (float(x[0]), float(x[1])), list(reader))
line = LineString(xy_floats)

num_points = 9  # includes first and last

new_points = [line.interpolate(i/float(num_points - 1), normalized=True) for i in range(num_points)]

with open('output_xy.txt', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerows([ [point.x, point.y] for point in new_points])
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Be aware that this is not equidistant on a sphere.

Comment: true, but for practical purposes it works well enough. Thanks again for the support @kvantour

Answer (score 1):

The following answer assumes that your coordinates are on a sphere and not on an ellipsoid.

Your input contains a set of points on the great-circle between two points *p* and *q* with coordinates in longitude and latitude to be:

```
p = {φp,λp} = {-78.0599088, -11.89402416}
q = {φq,λq} = {-77.38064244, -11.5446833099999}
```

Call ***n***<sub>p</sub> the unit vector of *p* and ***n***<sub>q</sub> the unit vector of *q*, then its coordinates are:

```
np = {cos(φp) cos(λp),cos(φp) sin(λp),sin(φp)}
nq = {cos(φq) cos(λq),cos(φq) sin(λq),sin(φq)}
```

Call α then angle between ***n***<sub>p</sub> and ***n***<sub>q</sub>

```
α = arccos(np·nq)
```

If you now want to have *n* points equidistantly spaced between *p* and *q*, you have to separate them over an angle Δα = α/(n-1).

The coordinates over these points are then:

```
ni = np cos(i Δα) + nr sin(i Δα)
nr = Normalized[nq - (nq·np) np] = (nq - cos(α) np) / sin(α)
```

for *i* ∈ [0,n-1]. The above is understood as a simple rotation over *iΔα* of ***n***<sub>p</sub> in the ***n***<sub>p</sub>-***n***<sub>r</sub> plane (***n***<sub>p</sub>·***n***<sub>r</sub> = 0)

These coordinates can then be transformed back to longitude and latitude, giving you all the intermediate points.

**remark:** This is for equidistant points on a sphere and not an ellipsoid such as [WGS 84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)

**remark:** The above will fail for antipodal points.

A very good formulary is [Ed William's Aviation Formulary](http://edwilliams.org/avform.htm)